# Erros custom field importin Junit XML with Xray and Jira

Tags: junit, cucumber, cypress, jira, jira-xray

When I try to import my XML from Junit I get the following error {"error":"Error creating issues in Jira! - Field Customer is required., Field Travelio: Dimension is required."} I know that this is beacue Xray is trying to create issues for the test cases imported and it cant create them becuse this custom fields. How I solve this?

Rigth now my commands are

```
token=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @"cloud_auth.json" "https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/authenticate"| tr -d '"')
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"  --data @"test-results.xml" https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/import/execution/junit?projectKey=PRB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the "Fields required" condition for Customer and Dimension fields from the workflow (or from the Field Configuration scheme if they are stated as "required" in here) before the import.

Then, you can do this XML import and revert the changes manually, again.